# bootstrap responsive container width doesn't work

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

So i have build quite complex website but it's all based on standard bootstrap template without any changes done to bootstrap.css
The thing is, for some reason navbar is always 15px wider than rest of the website. While on PC you cannot see the difference, on mobile there is this weird white space next to the container. Why is that? How do i limit navbar?
i tried overriding max-width of .navbar to calc(100%-15px) but it doesn't make any difference.[image]

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue in [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or post the code required.

Comment: actually i can show you website since it's already live (no idea why i blured out things). its http://ntechs.pl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you use the col command on the div below the navbar? If yes remove it. Of it still doesn't work, try clear: both command for the div under the navbar (not the white one). Hope that helps!

PS: It would be a lot more helpful if you post the CSS code (and HTML if necessary) so it will be easier to debug.

Comment: How about display: none (apply it on the white element)?

Comment: don't even know what is that white thing. it displays only on mobile phones and i can't really go into dev tools doing so

Comment: Erm... May I have a look at your HTML and CSS code?

Comment: This will be the best way to test it out.

Comment: i posted it on previous answer but sure: ntechs.pl

Comment: try overflow: hidden on the main page.

Comment: thank you! i tried to hide overflow in certain places but non worked. applying it to highest div "page" did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Change from position fixed to absolute.

```
.navbar-fixed-top, .navbar-fixed-bottom { position: absolute; }
```